# What does it mean when a discount lender "rediscount[s] reserves"?

Tags: macroeconomics, financial-economics, central-banking

I was reading a wikipedia article about the evolution of global financial system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_financial_system#Interwar_period:_1915%E2%80%931944.

In the passage about the pre-WWI financial system, it is written that

> [Immediately before the outbreak of WWI,] European tensions and
>   increasing political uncertainty motivated investors to chase
>   liquidity, prompting commercial banks to borrow heavily from London's
>   discount market. As the money market tightened, discount lenders began
>   rediscounting their reserves at the Bank of England rather than
>   discounting new pounds sterling.

What do "rediscounting reserves" and "discounting new pounds sterling" mean?